# How to Hide/Gray out Logging Code in Visual Studio Code (Eg: Python)

Tags: python, logging, visual-studio-code, ide

Can code lines in Visual Studio code be hidden/greyed out using a software setting or by installing a plugin?

Example of Python code to gray out or hide:

```
log.debug('This is a DEBUG level log message')
```

Visual Studio has a plugin that greys out logging code: [Gray Log Lines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ElmarXCV.GrayLogLines). However I am unable to find a similar plugin for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Did you ever find anything @nyxynyx

Comment: @DavidC Not yet, hope someone can help us find a solution to this

Comment: you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65692310/how-to-hide-or-collapse-all-javascript-console-log-lines-in-vsc