# How to hide or collapse all javascript console.log lines in VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code

Lots of logging is very helpful to me.

However, sometimes I would like to temporarily reduce the clutter of code that I'm editing in VSC by hiding, collapsing, or reducing the opacity of the font of `console.log`, `console.warn`, and `console.error` lines in javascript, Vue, React, etc.

[image]

How could I accomplish my goal?

I'd love if there were some way to easily toggle the feature on/off.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65426067/9938317

Answer (score 7):

Thank you so much to @rioV8, who pointed me to the answer.

**This seems to work for me** when using extension [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight):

```
"highlight.regexes": {
    "(console\\.(log|warn|error)\\(.+\\)[;]?)": {
        "regexFlags": "g",
        "decorations": [
          { "opacity": "0.1" }
        ]
      }
}
```

To determine what regular expression I wanted to use, I wrote these test cases in https://www.regexpal.com:

```
console.log('asdfdsf')
console.log({some})
console.log({some});
console.error('error', msg);
console.warn('careful', thing)
```

And `(console\.(log|warn|error)\(.+\)[;]?)` worked. Then I needed to add an extra `\` before each `\` to satisfy the VSC settings JSON file.

Now my VSC looks like this:

[image]

Comment: https://vscode.rocks/decorations/ also looks interesting, and this hack is helpful: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9078#issuecomment-390512079